# How to add a link in the controller message?

Tags: cakephp

I have designed an online shopping site in which I have included the "Compare Products" option.

So, after the compare button is clicked, a dismissable alert box with message, "Product Successfully Added to Compare" will be shown. But, I now need to give a link for the users to click and go directly to the compare page.

Like "Product successfully added to compare. You can view by clicking here".

But, I don't know how to add a link.

The code I used is,

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Product Successfully Added to Compare '), 'success');
```

Kindly tell me how to add a link to the message.

Comment: Does link is static?

Comment: Yes. The link is Static.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this in other link and works fine. T h a n k s   for your efforts and answers.

Try This.

1) Created new element `session_flash_link.ctp` in `app/views/elements`.

2) Added the following code in `session_flash_link.ctp`:

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="message"> 
<?php
echo $message;
echo $this->Html->link($link_text, $link_url, array("escape" => false));
?>
</div>
```

3) Code in controller:

```
$this->Session->setFlash("Shop has been successfully saved. ", "session_flash_link", array(
      "link_text" => "Return to Shop Management &raquo;",
      "link_url" => array(
        "controller" => "shops",
        "action" => "manage",
        "admin" => true
      )
 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
// access the html helper
$Html = (new View($this))->loadHelper('Html');
// use it to generate a link    
$resend = $Html->link(__('resend'), array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'resend',
));
// sprintf to insert the link to your standard message text!
$this->Session->setFlash(sprintf(_("Product Successfully Added to Compare."), $resend));
```

Comment: Check the answer I posted. I think I found the answer in other link.

Answer (score 0):

Easier and simple method without even using helper

```
    $this->Session->setFlash('Page not found <a href="'. Router::url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')) .'"> login here</a>', 'error');
```

Comment: Printing as it is. Like <a href="something"></a>.

Comment: $this->Session->setFlash('Product Successfully added to compare. <a href="'. Router::url(array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'compare')) .'"> Click here to see</a>', 'success');

Comment: Your code did not print as it. It fetches the link and shows. But, as text only and not as link.

Example: Product successfully added to compare. fetched link

Comment: I use the same code in my websites and it shows link not text

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Product Successfully Added to Compare <a href="link here">click here</a>');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Printing as it is. Like <a href="something"></a>.